# What's the theoretical upper bound for a speedup with python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I just tried to chunk my dataframe and process each chunk in parallel. Imagine my surprise when it took 16.5 minutes. The original process took 2.5 hours.

How is this possible? Using 4 cores, I thought I would the theoretical minimum speed achieved would be 2 hours 30 minutes % 4, or 37.5 minutes. I also assumed that given the overhead that multiprocessing has, precisely original time % 4 couldn't be achieved.

The code is below. The multiprocessing parts are commented out. I set up GANs using civis' project on GitHub and changed it to use my dataset. I refactored it out to separate methods in order to time the operations part specifically. I can't share my dataset, but it was 681,539 rows, 4 columns, and took up 6045KB as a csv.

```
import logging
import os
from zhou_utils import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import multiprocessing as mp

from dpwgan import CategoricalDataset
from dpwgan.utils import create_categorical_gan

INPUT = r"D:\ODM Data Task\Fake Data\Cleaned All Absences SY19-20.csv"
OUTPUT = r"D:\ODM Data Task\Fake Data\Fake Absences SY19-20.csv"

THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

NOISE_DIM = 15
HIDDEN_DIM = 20
SIGMA = 1

# read file
def read(file):
    try:
        return (pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str)
                .astype(str))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Error: Data files do not exist.\n'
              'Please run `create_absence_data.py` first.')
        return

# process file
@timeit.timeit
def operations(df):
    torch.manual_seed(123)
    dataset = CategoricalDataset(df)
    data = dataset.to_onehot_flat()

    gan = create_categorical_gan(NOISE_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, dataset.dimensions)

    # logger.info('Training GAN...')
    gan.train(data=data,
              epochs=50,
              n_critics=5,
              learning_rate=1e-4,
              weight_clip=1/HIDDEN_DIM,
              sigma=SIGMA)

    # logger.info(f'Generating synthetic data for {INPUT}...')
    flat_synthetic_data = gan.generate(len(df))
    return dataset.from_onehot_flat(flat_synthetic_data)

# parallel process the operations
# time this operation versus operations()
# @timeit.timeit
# def parallel_operations(pool, operations, df_chunks):
#     return pd.concat(pool.map(operations, df_chunks))

# visualize file
def visualize(df):
    df.to_csv(OUTPUT, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info(f'Preparing data set for {INPUT}...')

    # read file
    df = read(INPUT)

    # split into 4
    # df_chunks = np.array_split(df, 4)

    # apply parallel processing
    # with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    #     df = parallel_operations(pool,operations,df_chunks)

    # operate on dataframe
    df = operations(df)

    # visualize
    visualize(df)

    logger.info('Synthetic data saved to {}'.format(OUTPUT))
```

Comment: There is no theoretical upper bound. The original method may be doing something inefficient, like thrashing cache. When split into multiple threads, the inefficiency may decrease. For example, they might use smaller blocks of data that happen to fit in cache.